# Market Maker portfolio management

Tags: portfolio-management, market-microstructure, market-making, limit-order-book, strategy

I am interested in articles/strategies related to portfolio and inventory management for market makers and to management of order cancellation, updates of order, etc.

Most of the strategies from articles are related to a market maker who quotes only one line (one security). What about those who quotes several lines?

Comment: Would it be better to delete "and to management of order cancellation, updates of order, etc." from the question or is it ok that broad?

Comment: what do you mean by "quotes only one/several lines"? One/several lines from what?

Answer (score 1):

I can't provide any papers, but market makers tend to shift pricing by the current inventory they have in that asset. Furthermore they will shift pricing of asset A by the inventory they have in all assets similar to asset A.

The methodology for how much to shift by, whether to shift mid/bid/ask and what constitutes as 'similar' is what the market making firms compete on.